# How to display a leaflet map on a wordpress website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, leaflet

I have finished a leaflet map on codepen.
My code is splitted in html/css and javascript/jquery.
I would like to know how to display the map on a wordpress website.
I had try the embedding on codepen, but the fact there is ''Result on top left'' and ''edit on Codepen'' doesn't match my needs.
Do i have to make the code in a full html (My javascript inside  </>script then )?
Is there a easy way to display it?
Thank you very much

Comment: Codepen is not a free hosting service. You can make the same page on your WP instance by copying JS/CSS and HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following solution, which works for Elementor too.
Yes, do use the html, yet, add your css and js files inside your

> wp-content > themes > child-theme > assets > css or js folders

> link these files as you would in a standard html setting, either by typing up the whole permalink or in a shortened ../wp-content/etc. link.  I use the first option.

Add your html and it should work.

Tip 1:  Inside your browser, inspect for any errors, because if you have any older javascript , WordPress will issue a warning.

Tip 2:  If you use any images, you need to optimize the images like WordPress Media does.